# Javascript click event fired by enter keyup instead of keydown

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, jquery-events

Can you confirm me that click event on <kbd>A</kbd> or `BUTTON` element is fired also if I **keydown** the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> keyboard key?
I tried it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/w5z2xa3h/1/

Can I switch this default behavour to **keyup** instead of **keydown**?

Comment: Yup, it is indeed the click event, and looking into the the event object doesn't show anything different from a mouse click. So there doesn't seem to be anything you could use to distinguish the event.

Comment: If you are concerned about this for some reason, you could try setting tab index to `-1`. It should prevent the `A` element from getting focus through tabbing.

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent the default behavior of the `keydown` event if the key is <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. But you need to store some information (the element that been keydowned) so you can simulate a click on it on `keyup`:

```js
$(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){$("a")[0].focus();},1000);
});

$(document).on("click", ".alert", function(e) {
    $("body").append('<div>Click fired!</div>');
});



var awaitingClick = null;                               // used to keep track of the element that been keydowned (also used to check if there is an element)
$(document).on("keydown", ".alert", function(e) {       // when a keydown on .alert element happens
    if(e.keyCode === 13) {                              // if the key is Enter (keyCode of 13)
        awaitingClick = $(this);                        // store this element (to be click-simulated on keyup)
        e.preventDefault();                             // prevent the default behavior (clicking the element)
    }
});

$(document).on("keyup", function(e) {                   // when a keyup event occur (no need to specify .alert element as that is unnecessary)
    if(awaitingClick) {                                 // if awaitingClick isn't null (there is an element awaiting to be clicked as it has been keydowned by Enter)
        awaitingClick.click();                          // then simulate a click on it
        awaitingClick = null;                           // and awaiting no more!!!
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><a class="alert" href=#>Tab and focus here and push and maintain ENTER pushed!</a></p>
```

**Note:** Once you press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, you can only delay the click for as long as you keep the key down. If you want to be able to cancel the click, you could add another `keydown` event listener for, for example, the <kbd>ESCAPE</kbd> key that sets `awaitingClick` to `null`. That way when you keyup <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, the element won't be click-simulated as `awaitingClick` is set to `null`:

```js
$(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){$("a")[0].focus();},1000);
});

$(document).on("click", ".alert", function(e) {
    $("body").append('<div>Click fired!</div>');
});



var awaitingClick = null;
$(document).on("keydown", ".alert", function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode === 13) {
        awaitingClick = $(this); 
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    if(e.keyCode === 27) {                              // if ESCAPE is pressed
        awaitingClick = null;                           // then mission abort (set awaitingClick to null that way when keyup happens the click won't be simulated)
    }
});

$(document).on("keyup", function(e) {
    if(awaitingClick) {                                 // awaitingClick could be set to null before keyup of ENTER had happened (in that case no click is simulated)
        awaitingClick.click();
        awaitingClick = null;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<strong>Press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, keep it down, and then press <kbd>ESCAPE</kbd> to cancel the click by <kbd>ENTER</kbd></strong><br>
<p><a class="alert" href=#>Tab and focus here and push and maintain ENTER pushed!</a></p>
```